# Hibernate validator field name

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

How to make hibernate validator return field name instead of "arg0" when using @NotBlank validator?

```
@NotBlank
@FormParam("address")
private String address;
```

returns when empty:

```
{arg0: may not be empty}
```

Comment: Why not add the @Column("address") annotation

Comment: You might have to register a ParameterNameProvider

Answer (score 2):

You should only see this kind of synthetic parameter name during method (or constructor) validation. You can plug-in a custom `ParameterNameProvider` which returns parameter names e.g. from a custom annotation or debug symbols.

Hibernate Validator already comes with a [custom implementation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-paranamer-parameternameprovider) based on the ParaNamer library which provides runtime access to parameter names these and other approaches. Once Java 8 is out, it'll be very easy to implement a parameter name provider using the Java 8 API for accessing parameter names.